# Как YouTube идентифицирует мой компьютер?

Tags: браузер, youtube

Я постоянно удаляю всю историю все куки, вообщем все с браузера. Я по умолчанию не залогинен в браузере ни в каких соц.сетях вообще нигде. Браузер полностью чистый. никаких расширений кроме стандартных тоже нет. IP адрес как я понимаю тоже не может служить отправной точкой так как он скорее всего выдается один на весь город или типа того.

Я посмотрел видео на ютубе про дарк нет. Потом все почистил закрыл браузер потом посмотрел фильм далекий от этой тематики захожу в ютуб а он мне советует видео про дарк нет, как такое может быть?

Вроде MAC адрес на сколько я знаю не выходит дальше моего роутера. В чем может быть причина? Как YouTube меня смог идентифицировать? Повторюсь браузер полностью чист от куки истории и прочего, удаляю всё.

Comment: гугл: «ага, тут объявился ещё один аноним с публичного ip-адреса. какой бы список роликов ему предложить? хм, а на какие темы с этого ip-адреса были последние запросы? ну, вот и предложим ролики на эти темы. авось что-нибудь анониму понравится». аноним: «а! гугл угадал мои предпочтения: среди предложенных роликов есть ролик интересующей меня тематики!». гугл: «ух ты! из десятка предложенных роликов с одним я таки угадал!»

Answer (score 0):

Насколько  я знаю у видеокарты есть универсальная комбинация при помощи которой тебя можно идентифицировать независимо от всего остального. Возможно что Google использует эти данные чтобы тебя вычислить. Подробнее об этом ты можешь посмотреть здесь:

> https://youtu.be/nxD96qu_Mzg

UPD: В источнике однако говорится, что Google этого не делает, но тем не менее, информация может быть не актуальна, или же не точна, поэтому оставлю ответ как один из возможных вариантов.

Comment: Уникальные серийники есть у много какого оборудования (матплата, CPU, HDD/SSD) . Но где подтверждения того, что код из браузера имеет к ним доступ?

Comment: Мы можем проверить это используя утилиты из видео выше. Но конкретно в данном случае говорится о видеокарте,  именно потому-что с её усилий отрисовывается Canvas, который вызывается из JavaScript.